# Adding Web API to existing application with virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, iis, kentico

I have an existing website setup and working (kentico 10), I want to add Web API to it using a virtual directory.

I setup the web api project and it works when I map IIS to it as a normal site. However when I map the folder as a virtual directory and convert to application into my kentico site I get errors. What I dont understand is why I am getting errors originating from the kentico web config and not the new web api web.config/service:

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Web' does not exist in the namespace 'CMS.Base' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 47:       <namespaces>
Line 48:         <add namespace="CMS.Helpers" />
Line 49:         <add namespace="CMS.Base.Web.UI" />
Line 50:       </namespaces>
Line 51:     </pages>
```

I did try adding these DLLs into the bin of the web api project which stopped this error but I couldnt retrieve data as expected from kentico in the web-api project.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you create an application within a website in IIS, the parent web.config will be inherited by the sub applications very similar to how a main website inherits the "global" web.config.  Maybe not all of the nodes will be inherited but a lot of them will be.

So what you'll want to do is add  (i.e.: `<remove name="WebDAVModule" />`) nodes to areas in which you want to remove namespaces or such in your newly created sub application's web.config.  I cannot say specifically which nodes will need to have those  nodes applied but trial and error should help.  If you follow the errors that come on-screen, they should help with adding those nodes in your child web.config.